# How to do TypeScript tsdoc documentation for function argument with generic type that extends an interface?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, tsdoc

Consider the following code, note the documentation of `someField`:

```js
interface Test {
    /**
     * Some description.
     * lorum ipsum.
     * foo bar.
     */
    someField: string;
}

function withGeneric<T extends Test>(arg: T) {
    return arg;
}

function withoutGeneric(arg: Test) {
    return arg;
}

withGeneric({
    someField: ""
});

withoutGeneric({
    someField: ""
});
```

When I hover with my mouse over `someField` in the `withoutGeneric` call, VSCode nicely shows me the documentation:

[image]

However, when hovering over `someField` in the `withGeneric` call, the documentation is not shown:

[image]

Is there a way to make the tsdoc documentation work with the generic argument too?

Comment: At that point it doesn't know whether that's actually Test or some other type that fulfils T, so it doesn't know whether it's Test.someField. If you supplied Test as the generic explicitly I'd guess you'd get it back.

Comment: What do you mean supply test as the generic explicitly?

Comment: `withGeneric<Test>(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Consider that when you create the inline object, it is not typed as `Test`:

```
const config = {
    someField: ""
};
```

[image]

Your `withoutGeneric` function, by definition, takes a `Test`-typed argument, so TypeScript can infer the property types. However, when your function is generic but you don't explicitly set the generic type then TypeScript will infer the generic type from the inline object's type, which is just the default inferred type you can see above.

You can see this in the intellisense:

[image]

TypeScript is inferring the generic type as `{ someField: string; }`. This satisfies the requirements of the `Test` interface, but the value is its own inferred default type, not `Test`.

Consider the following example:

```
interface Foobar {
    /**
     * Unrelated doc string
     */
    someField: string;
}

const config:Foobar = {
    someField: ""
}
```

You get the following intellisense:

[image]

Note that the `withGeneric` function is satisfied by the `Foobar` type because it has the required properties and they are of the correct type. However, the doc string associated with `someField` would be `Unrelated doc string` because that is the type of the `config` variable.

If you explicitly set the generic type of your function, then it will behave as you expected.

```
withGeneric<Test>({
    someField: ""
});
```

Yields the following:

[image]

If you explicitly set the type to `Foobar`, then you'll get Foobar's doc strings:

```
withGeneric<Foobar>({
    someField: ""
});
```

yields:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer that works for my purpose. Add a union with the extended from type:

```js
/**
 * withGeneric sample
 * @typeParam T - must be a Test
 * @param arg 
 * @returns 
 */
function withGeneric<T extends Test>(arg: T & Test) {
    return arg;
}
```

Now VSCode does show the documentation:

[image]

It feels like a trick, but I fail to see any disadvantages to it?

Comment: I don't know of any immediate issue with this approach, but it makes me wonder what you were trying to get out of the generic argument in the first place. If you are going to use explicit typing, then why bother with the generic?

Comment: For example, taking the `Foo` interface from my answer and calling `withGeneric<Foo>({...})`, your function now returns not `Foo` but `Foo & Test`